# How to prevent the rounding of seconds in smallDateTime

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2

After using SQL Server for many years I have only just today noticed how it rounds `SmallDateTime` values to the nearest minute (can not believe I have not noticed this before!). I want to store seconds, how can I achieve this?

I am using SQL Server 208R2. If this is a value in my query:

```
2014-08-11 09:15:22
```

it ends up in the table like so:

```
2014-08-11 09:15:00
```

Comment: [smalldatetime](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182418.aspx) - Defines a date that is combined with a time of day. The time is based on a 24-hour day, with seconds **always zero (:00)** and without fractional seconds.

Comment: If you need seconds, don't use `SMALLDATETIME`. For SQL Server **2008** and newer, I would recommend using `DATETIME2(n)` which allows you to define just how many fractional digits of the second you need - and it's also precise to 100ns (rather than 3.33ms like the old `DATETIME`).

Comment: So I figure if the datatype can not be changed its simply not possible to capture seconds.  Thank you for your advice.